# What film or TV show is being referenced in Psych episode Santabarbaratown?

Tags: reference, psych

At the end of the finale of [*Psych*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0491738/) season 6, called *"Santabarbaratown"*, Gus and Shawn have an exchange wherein Shawn says, referring to Dahlia Twon, *"his sister, his girlfriend, his girlfriend, his sister"*, to which Gus responds, *"...It's just Santa Barbara"*. I know that many *Psych* episodes (especially those of season 6) often parody or reference other works. It seams like this is what they were doing here.

What were they referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is reference to [**Chinatown**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071315/).

There is [a scene between](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071315/quotes) **Jake Gittes** *(Jack Nicholson)* and **Evelyn Mulwray** *(Faye Dunaway)* that goes:

> - **Evelyn Mulwray:** *She's my daughter.*
>
>   [Gittes slaps Evelyn]
>
>   **Jake Gittes:** *I said I want the truth!*
>
>   **Evelyn Mulwray:** *She's my sister...*
>
>   [slap]
>
>   **Evelyn Mulwray:** *She's my daughter...*
>
>   [slap]
>
>   **Evelyn Mulwray:** *My sister, my daughter.*
>
>   [More slaps]
>
>   **Jake Gittes:** *I said I want the truth!*
>
>   **Evelyn Mulwray:** *She's my sister AND my daughter!*

- [Watch the scene on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnrdetFAo1o#t=01m11s)

---

In the **American Film Institute**'s list [**AFI's 100 Years... 100 Movie Quotes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AFI%27s_100_Years...100_Movie_Quotes) the line

> *Forget it, Jake, it's Chinatown.*

is listed as #74.

- [Watch the scene on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uSz0mEtEsQ#t=01m02s)

> In addition to *"Forget it, Jake, it's Chinatown,"* another line of the film's dialogue that has become famous is *"She's my daughter. She's my sister...She's my sister and my daughter,"* spoken by Dunaway ...   [[Source](http://www.afi.com/members/catalog/DetailView.aspx?s=&Movie=54409)]

Comment: There a couple of _Chinatown_ references, including the episode's __title__.

Comment: Yeah, I immediately thought about *Chinatown* when reading *Gus*'s quote, but then thought that the original *"Forget it, Jake. It's Chinatown"* doesn't match that well. But together with *Shawn*'s quote (whose *Chinatown* original I didn't immediately remember) and the episode title, this seems a perfect fit. Maybe you might want to include the characteristic *Chinatown* quote (the one matching *Gus*) as an additional argument and move the mentioning of the title from the comments into the answer. As they all together give a pretty good proof of the *Chinatown* reference.

Comment: @ChristianRau - There are a few more references, e.g the victim's name is _Veronica Towne_, wich alludes to _Chinatown's_ writer [Robert Towne](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001801/). And there is a waitress named _Ida_, which is a reference to the character _Ida Sessions_ in _Chinatown_.

Answer (score 3):

For Santabarbaratow episode, following are the references mentioned by IMDb.

> - Shawn refers to Gus as the "candy man," and he replies, "I make the
>     world taste good." Refers to [Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory
>     (1971).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willy_Wonka_&_the_Chocolate_Factory)
> - Thea tells Shawn and Gus that she and Jordan watched "Summer School"
>     the night before. [Summer School (1987)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willy_Wonka_&_the_Chocolate_Factory)
> - Shawn asks Thea if she watched "Ski School" the night before.- [Ski
>     School (1990)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ski_School_%28film%29)
> - Shawn refers to Henry as "Sipowicz." -Refers to [NYPD Blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NYPD_Blue) (1993) (TV
>     Series)
> - Shawn asks Chief Vick: "Did you see the season finale of 'The
>     Bachelorette'?"- refers to The [Bachelorette (2003) (TV Series)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0348894/).
> - Shawn and Gus discuss the  movie.-[The Lincoln Lawyer (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1189340/)
> - **As Thea is carried away, Gus says, "Forget about it, Shawn; it's just
>     Santa Barbara." Refers to [Chinatown (1974)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071315/)**
>
> (Source:[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2092746/trivia?tab=mc))

Comment: Ah, I also thought immediately about *Chinatown*, but *Gus*'s quote didn't match that well, but together with the previous sentence (that the OP left out, didn't see this season myself, yet) it is pretty obvious. Also take a look at *Oliver*'s answer for even more *Chinatown* references.